# Hostapd on Pi Connection failed

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, hostapd, wifi-direct

I am using a PI 3B+ and the Rasbian light Version on it. I build the hostapd on my PI with wget, so that i can make modifications on it. After building and starting (build and make) the hostapd, started the hostapd with (sudo ./hostapd hostapd2.conf). The Pi showed up on my other PI in the list of Wifis and i tried to connect to it but it doesn't really work.
This is what it shows:

```
    $ sudo ./hostapd hostapd2.conf

wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED 
wlan0: STA b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c IEEE 802.11: associated
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c
wlan0: STA b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c RADIUS: starting accounting session 849DC5A0325D6BC7
wlan0: STA b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (WPA)
wlan0: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c
wlan0: STA b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c WPA: group key handshake completed (WPA)
^Cwlan0: interface state ENABLED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED b8:27:eb:54:0c:9c
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

My hostapd.config looks like this:

```
    interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=pi_ap
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
logger_syslog_level=1
```

My second Pi is connected but the internet doesn't work on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found my mistake and how to set it up. I had to follow the following instruction without installing the hostapd. https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/